# The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: model

Tags: codeigniter, hook

I load my models like this

```
class Admin_user extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        CheckLoginIn();

        $this->load->model('admin_user_model','model');
    }

        function index(){
           //my function..
        }
     }
```

Initially every thing was good...
then i had to use hooks..

my hooks.php file

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
    'class'    => 'MyClass',
    'function' => 'get_code',
    'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

now i get this error.

```
The model name you are loading is the name of a resource that is already being used: model
```

however if i set `$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;` everything works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer.. i had to user `post_controller_constructor` instead of `pre_controller` so my hooks file will be

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'MyClass',
    'function' => 'get_code',
    'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```